# Form does not exists in current context

Tags: c#, winforms

Upon clicking a login button I would like to hide the login form and display a login confirmation form along with a second form containing a sidebar. When I click the button I receive a "does not exist in current context" error.

```
public partial class Dashboad : Form
{
    public Dashboad()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int imageNumber = 1;

    public void LoadNextLoad()
    {
        if (imageNumber == 10)
        {
            imageNumber = 1;
        }
        slider.ImageLocation = string.Format(@"images/{0}.jpg", imageNumber);
        imageNumber++;
    }

    private void slideTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadNextLoad();
    }

    private void Dashboad_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void LeftPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void BodyPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public partial class loginForm : Form
{
    public loginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        SideBarMenu menu = new SideBarMenu();
        menu.TopLevel = false;
        menu.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        menu.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        LeftPanel.Controls.Clear();
        LeftPanel.Controls.Add(menu);
        menu.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `LeftPanel` and where is it declared? The only thing we see is that one function, so all we can say is "yes, it is not in the current scope".

Comment: i edited it and add where the LeftPanel was declared

Comment: `LeftPanel` is part of your `Dashboad` (dashboard?) form, not `loginForm`. It is not available in the login form scope, so you can't access it there.

Comment: pls, can i create a method on a dashboard form and write the code in it, then call it up when the login_btn is click

Comment: I don't see how your login form is related to the dashboard form so I can't tell you if that is a viable approach.

Comment: sir, pls how possibly can i send them to you so you can help me out, am stock here